# Unity hit.rigidbody reference to concrete gameObject

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, gameobject

I've got Menu with 3d texts. Main Camera has got animations that I want to play after clicking on text. Every text has its own rigidbody and collider. I made this code:

```
#pragma strict
import UnityEngine;
var object : GameObject;
var Run : AnimationPlay;
function start(){
Run = object.GetComponent(AnimationPlay);
}
function Update() {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
        var hit: RaycastHit;
        var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, hit)) {
            if (hit.rigidbody != null){
                Debug.Log("Start Game pushed");
                Run.action = true;
                }
        }
    }
}
```

for Start Game button and this one:

```
#pragma strict
import UnityEngine;
var object : GameObject;
var Run : AnimationPlay2;
function start(){
Run = object.GetComponent(AnimationPlay2);
}
function Update() {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
        var hit: RaycastHit;
        var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, hit)) {
            if (hit.rigidbody != null){
                Debug.Log("Back pushed");
                Run.action2 = true;
                }
        }
    }
}
```

for Back button.
The problem is it's no matter on which rigidbody I will click, both animations are starting to play and that makes weird effects. I don't know how to make a reference to concrete gameObject's rigidbody.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. I replaced

```
hit.rigidbody != null
```

with

```
hit.rigidbody.gameObject.tag == "StartGame" //object's tag here
```

and now it works fine.